# I cannot use history.pushState while using angular's $location service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ngroute

https://jsfiddle.net/leathan/8bstxhc6/4/

Basically in the above jsfiddle if you remove `$location` from the above code and then run it and click the link before 7 seconds you are alerted "Did_it_work". If you do not remove `$location` then it breaks when you click the link.

**EDIT:** pushState also breaks if I use the tag ng-include ...

Comment: what `$location` in the above code?

Comment: fixed it in the new link

Comment: To avoid conflicts with the AngularJS framework, avoid using `pushState` directly. Instead use the [AngularJS $location.state() method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#state) to push state. The `$location` service is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Comment: can I have an example? Im not sure how to use $location.state()

Comment: `state([state]);` yet i tried `$location.state("","","test")` and it didnt work?

Comment: the docs just say you need to pass in a state object but i have no idea what a state object is, where do the docs explain this stuff? always confuses me

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: post what you said as an answer and ill accept, thanks you led me to the ultimate answer which was `$location.state({foo:'bar'}).path('bla')`

Answer (score 1):

As @georgaewg pointed out AngularJS digest cycle was causing my code to break.

`$location.path()` is actually enough for what I needed.

`$location.state({foo:'bar'}).path('path_here')` for example would work if I wanted to store $location.state().foo.